# ¿Cómo obtengo el ID único del procesador en C#?

Tags: c#

Estoy trabajando en un software y necesito obtener el ID único del procesador de la máquina en la que correrá el sistema para autorizarlo utilizando C#.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y probaste, intentaste o investigaste algo al respecto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener informacion de hardware puedes usar `WMI`

[Get the system’s board serial numbers and CPU IDs in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/12/use-wmi-to-get-the-systems-board-serial-numbers-and-cpu-ids-in-c/)

basicamente realizas la query

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard
```

a WMI usando as clases de c#

```
private List GetBoardSerialNumbers()
{
    List results = new List();

    string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard";
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
        new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
    foreach (ManagementObject info in searcher.Get())
    {
        results.Add(
            info.GetPropertyValue("SerialNumber").ToString());
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, lo probaré

Answer (score 0):

ya me había topado con este problema con anterioridad, desarrollé los siguientes métodos que espero te sean de utilidad:

```
    public static string ObtenerCPUId()
    {
        string cpuInfo = String.Empty;
        try
        {

            System.Management.ManagementClass mgmt = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
            System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection objCol = mgmt.GetInstances();
            foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject obj in objCol)
            {
                if (cpuInfo == String.Empty)
                {
                    cpuInfo = obj.Properties["ProcessorId"].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            if (cpuInfo == String.Empty)
                cpuInfo = "CPUID";


        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            LogHandler.GenerarErrorLog("ERROR AL OBTENER ID DE PROCESADOR", exp);
            cpuInfo = "0";
        }

        return cpuInfo.Trim();

    }

    public static string ObtenerHDId(string drive)
    {
        string volumeSerial = "HDID";
        try
        {
            ManagementObject dsk = new ManagementObject(@"win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=""" + drive + @":""");
            dsk.Get();
            volumeSerial = dsk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            LogHandler.GenerarErrorLog("ERROR AL OBTENER ID DE DISCO DURO", exp);
            volumeSerial = "1";
        }

        return volumeSerial.Trim();
    }

    public static string ObtenerMotherBoardID()
    {
        string serial = "MBID";
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                serial = (string)mo["SerialNumber"];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            LogHandler.GenerarErrorLog("ERROR AL OBTENER ID DE TARJETA MADRE", exp);
            serial = "2";
        }

        return serial.Trim();
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, lo probaré